# How to make the right element remains on the same line while the left element wrap?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have been playing with this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/ArfUA/10/.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="short">1234</span>
  <span class="long ellipsis">LongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongWord</span>
</div>

<br />
<hr />
<br />


<div class="container">
  <span class="short">12345678910</span>
  <span class="long ellipsis">LongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongWord</span>
</div>

<br />
<hr />
<br />

<div class="container">
  <span class="short">1234</span>
  <span class="long ellipsis">LongLongLongLongWord</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width:400px;
    border:dashed 1px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.short {
    float: right;
    background: yellow; /*just for demo; */
}
.long
{
    display: block;
    background: pink; /*just for demo; */
}
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

It let the number on the right stays on the same line while the text on the left become '...' when the space is full.

I was wondering if it's possible to make the left text wrap to the next line instead of becoming '...'. I give it a try but it's not working. Can anybody point me out the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [word-break: break-all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) to achieve the effect you want.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: dashed 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.short {
  background: yellow;
  order: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.long {
  background: pink;
  word-break: break-all;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="short">1234</span>
  <span class="long ellipsis">LongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongWord</span>
</div>

<br />
<hr />
<br />


<div class="container">
  <span class="short">12345678910</span>
  <span class="long ellipsis">LongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongWord</span>
</div>

<br />
<hr />
<br />

<div class="container">
  <span class="short">1234</span>
  <span class="long ellipsis">LongLongLongLongWord</span>
</div>
```